# How to use constructor for Javascript client

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I'm experimenting with a simple Javascript API client but not sure on how to implement the constructor pattern.

So far I have this (based on Stripe's NodeJS client):

```
//myapp.js
'use strict';

MyApp.DEFAULT_HOST = 'api.myapp.io';
MyApp.DEFAULT_PORT = '443';
MyApp.DEFAULT_BASE_PATH = '/v1/';

function MyApp() {
    if(!(this instanceof MyApp)) {
        return new MyApp();
    }

}

MyApp.prototype = {
    init: function(appId) {
        console.log("Initializing");
    }
}
```

and in the HTML file I have:

```
...
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var client = new MyApp();
        client.init('12345');
    </script>
</head>
...
```

I don't want users of this client to need to add the `var client = new MyApp();` line. How can I modify `myapp.js` so that users only need to use the `MyApp.init('12345');` line like this:

```
...
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        MyApp.init('12345');
    </script>
</head>
...
```

Comment: This sounds like you want `MyApp` to be a singleton - which is neither a good practise nor has anything to do with constructors.

Comment: Unless you are executing side effects, don't use an `init` method but just put everything in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks. So if everything was in the constructor how would I pass the app ID?

Comment: Constructors have parameters as well.

Comment: I realise that constructors have parameters too but from the perspective of someone using the SDK what would they need to do to pass the AppId from the HTML file? A quick example would be good. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you want MyApp to be a singleton - which is neither a good practise nor has anything to do with constructors.

Don't use an init method but just put everything in the constructor:

```
function MyApp(appId) {
    if(!(this instanceof MyApp)) {
        return new MyApp(appId);
    }
    console.log("Initializing instance "+appId);
}
MyApp.DEFAULT_HOST = 'api.myapp.io';
MyApp.DEFAULT_PORT = '443';
MyApp.DEFAULT_BASE_PATH = '/v1/';

MyApp.prototype = … // add other methods
```

Your user would then just call `var client = new MyApp('12345')`. But notice that any side effects (like registering the instance in the DOM or something) should go in a separate method called on `client`.

If you want to simplify the instance creation, you can also use static methods, for example something like

```
function MyApp(appId) {
    console.log("Initializing instance "+appId);
}
MyApp.create = function(appId) {
    return new MyApp(appId);
};
MyApp.init = function(appId, …) {
    var client = this.create(appId);
    client.register(…);
    client.start(…);
    … // whatever
    return client;
};
```

Comment: To simulate purely static objects, I like to use json objects. Is there any caveat of doing this? It worked quite well in some projects where a similar pattern was needed.

Comment: @Frederik.L I assume you mean object literals with methods, not JSON? But yes, that's fine, they should be preferred over a class when you don't need instances. Just make sure they don't contain singleton-like global state.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I was mistakenly calling it json objects because of the similar notation. The difference is quite interesting, after some digging it appears that the difference is that an object literal isn't necessarily using string keys and valid json values (e.g. a function isn't valid), hence object literal != json object. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `MyApp.init`, `init` should be a static method:

```
function MyApp(appId) {
  if(!(this instanceof MyApp)) {
    return MyApp.init(appId);
  }
  // ...
}
MyApp.init = function(appId) {
  return new MyApp(appId);
};
```

Comment: Could you explain why `init` should be a static method please?

Comment: @tommyd456 Because `init` creates instances, so it makes no sense to call it on a instance.